# SAPUI5 - Dynamic odata binding to select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, sapui5

I am working on the select box binding. I want to bind data to the select box which is coming from odata service. Below is my code. My model is set and I can get the model value in the console. But not able to bind to select box.

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel("rulelist");
var Zid = '0';
var Zidentifier1 = 'Default Vendor';
var Zidentifier2 = '111111';
var aFilter = [];
var noModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
aFilter.push(new Filter("Zid", FilterOperator.EQ, Zid));
aFilter.push(new Filter("Zidentifier1", FilterOperator.EQ, Zidentifier1));
aFilter.push(new Filter("Zidentifier2", FilterOperator.EQ, Zidentifier2));
oModel.read("/ZruleAttributeSet", {
    filters: aFilter,
    success: function(data) {
    var attrResult = data.results;
    var headerFields = "";
    var aTtributes = [];
        for (var k = 0; k < attrResult.length; k++) {

        aTtributes.push({attribute:attrResult[k].Zattribute}); 
        headerFields += "attribute: "+attrResult[k].Zattribute + ",";
        }
        noModel.setData({
            items: aTtributes
        });
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(noModel, "newData");
        console.log(sap.ui.getCore().getModel("newData"));
        noModel.refresh(true);

    },
    error: function(e) {
        MessageToast.show("No Data Found !!");
    }
```

Comment: Please format your coding in an appropriate way to allow other users reading it easily.

Comment: Please post your view code where you binding JSON model to a select box

Answer (score 0):

If this is an oData service you should use the oData model - probably `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`.

Maybe the Data Binding and oData V4 [tutorials](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218%22Tutorial%22) might help you out?